# How to delete empty strings from localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Every time I refresh the page, it creates empty strings in my localstorage and every time it does it creates empty elements on my web and I don't want that. How can I fix this?

```
function saveLocalTodos(todo) {
    //check
    let todos;
    if(localStorage.getItem('todos') === null){
        todos = [];
    }else {
        todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'))
    }
    

    todos.push(todo);
    localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
}

window.onload = function() {

    const storedData = localStorage.getItem("todos");
  
   
    if (storedData && storedData !== "") {
      
        let todos;
        if(localStorage.getItem('todos') === null){
            todos = [];
        }else {
            todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'))
        } else {
      
        localStorage.removeItem('todos')
    };
}
```

Comment: `localStorage` stores strings so `if(localStorage.getItem('todos') === null)` should be `if(localStorage.getItem('todos') === "")`  because `null` != `""`.

Comment: Your logic is off. The second part of `storedData && storedData !== ""` is not necessary since the empty string is falsy. Also, `storedData` can't be `null` if it's truthy.

Comment: @InSync The logic is fine, it's just that the implementation of the logic has some redundant code that could be removed. It wouldn't change the outcome though.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yes, that's what I meant when I say "*[off](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/off)*".

Comment: unsure how you are getting empty strings on refresh. Have you added debugging statements to figure out what is happening in the code. `console.log()` and `debugger` are a developer's friend.

Comment: Why are you calling `localStorage.getItem('todos')` three times in the onload handler? Just call it once, then use the `storedData` variable!

Comment: @ScottMarcus `getItem` returns `null` when the given key does not exist at all in the storage. It returns the empty string only if an empty string value was stored for the key.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could refactor to something like:

```js
const getTodosInStorage = () => {
  const rawTodos = localStorage.getItem('todos');
  const currentTodos = !!rawTodos ? JSON.parse(rawTodos) : [];
  return currentTodos;
};

const saveLocalTodos = (todo) => {
  const currentTodos = getTodosInStorage();
  const todos = JSON.stringify([...currentTodos, todo]);
  localStorage.setItem('todos', todos);
};

window.onload = () => {
  const initialTodos = getTodosInStorage();
  // Do whatever you need to do with the initial
  // already existing todos.
};
```

This way you don't need to care if you have empty-string in the `localStorage` item. You will always get what you can find. The only thing is that you need to make sure you will have the next scenarios:

1. You'll get `null` or `''` when calling `localStorage.getItem('todos')`
2. You'll be setting either a valid JSON array stringified or an empty-string when invoking `localStorage.setItem('todos', /*whatever*/)`

With this, you'll get consistency when looking for the `todos` in the `localStorage`.